# Liberar memoria C Selenium y Drivers

Tags: c, eclipse, selenium, memoria, cucumber

Últimamente he estado usando Selenium y Cucumber en Eclipse. El caso es que la memoria C de mi PC se ha agotado y tenía espacio más que suficiente.
He buscado y parece ser que al instanciar los drivers en mi programa, estos consumen memoria. Lo que no se es donde puedo "borrar" o liberar el espacio que estos consumen. Ya he finalizado en administrador de tareas las instancias de browser creados por ellos, pero siguen ocupando espacio. Alguna idea de como puedo liberar este espacio?

Gracias y disculpad las molestias.

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Esta es una pregunta sobre programación? Si es así, deja el código con el que necesites ayuda.

Comment: Si te refieres a la memoria del disco nada que hacer, debes solicitar a  tu unidad IT que aumente el espacio del disco, si es la memoria ram puedes usar el driver.quit o ejecutar un comando en consola por medio de java para cerrar todas las intancias del driver. Saludos.

Comment: Ya he podido resolverlo. Al parecer se me almacenaban archivos en la carpeta temp. Borrando o como bien dice Alex utilizando el driver.quit se ha solucionado. Muchas gracias a ambos.